# Linux server with no video adapter

Tags: linux, ssh, home-server

I have an old AMD Athlon II X2 system that I was thinking of installing Linux (not decided on distro) onto to use as a server (e.g. Minecraft), but it does not have a display output, the Athlons don't have integrated graphics, neither does the 870 (IIRC) motherboard chipset.

So for this purpose I really don't have much use for a display at all, I will just SSH into it from other locations, so I do not really want to have to buy even a low end graphics card (the only spares I could locate were AGP).

Is it possible to run a system with no display output, e.g. some way of installing Linux that immediately makes SSH available to run through the installation with? Failing that I might be able to borrow one of those USB display adapters (does that work without a proper primary and installed OS?) or possibly a full graphics card, but then after installation would need to hand those back.

Comment: So you have no budget for even a $10 PCI card? Running headless is fine, but good luck booting to install an OS without a video card...

Comment: Well if I can install and then run without a GPU, then that works. I did look at buying a GPU, but the cheapest I quickly found was a HD 5450 that comes to £23 after postage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your keywords / search expressions are "headless workstation" and "linux installation"

e.g.

http://www.shekhargovindarajan.com/tips-n-tricks/install-fedora-14-linux-without-a-monitor-headless-keyboard-and-cddvd/

also: https://serverfault.com/questions/21255/headless-linux-install

Comment: Welcome to SU. While you give some helpful clues, you should avoid link-only answers (links may get offline and render your answer useless). Instead give a summary and include the links _only as a reference_.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. But if the same question is already answered to, what is the purpose of having another thread with detailed answers? Aren't the original posters spoiled? :)

Comment: The audience of _Superuser_ and _Serverfault_ is different, so good answers at SF might be overkill here. (The community decides by voting). Concerning quoting of other answers, I found [this post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7431/what-is-the-proper-way-to-cite-an-answer-from-another-stackexchange-site) at _Meta.SU_, where you can [discuss about SU](http://superuser.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Id agree with that, if I went to Serverfault putting "headless" as the correct technical term is probably an expectation, and not something Google told me on my attempt at a search for this.